# getting error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') using github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

Hi so I'm trying to use github pages to showcase my react project. The issue I'm having is my project runs just fine locally but when I attempt to use ***github pages*** I'm having a **blank screen** with this error, when inspecting the console log:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')**

[image: 1]

I'm only using useState in app.jsx and questions.jsx

[**App.jsx code below:**](https://github.com/ToxicTerror21/trivia-game/blob/master/src/App.jsx)

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import React from "react"

const [correctcount, setCount] = useState([false,false,false,false,false])
const [isShown, SetShow] = useState(true)
const [apidata, SetData] = useState([])
const [checkanswers,SetAnswers] = useState(false);
const[refresh,SetRefresh] =useState(false);
const[finalscore,SetScore] =useState(0);
```

[**questions.jsx code below:**](https://github.com/ToxicTerror21/trivia-game/blob/master/src/components/Questions.jsx)

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from 'react'

 const [selected, SetSelected] = useState(5);
 const[qorder,SetOrder] = useState(props.questions);
```

Not sure whats causing this to happen, heres a link to my github repo if that helps:

https://github.com/ToxicTerror21/trivia-game

Comment: It's probably because "props.questions" is null, I suggest debugging "questionsx" variable

Comment: Ya will try debugging that to see, thanks

Comment: Okay figured it out, basically it was 2 issues: The first being the usestate was being defined as null and the second mistake I was making I wasn't properly pushing the GitHub pages correctly. So even though I was making those changes to fix that null issue the github pages didn't update to reflect that. Now everything works.

Comment: How did you get useState to not be null?

Comment: @Malice Within questions.jsx I set the qorder state later on checking if props.questions is null before updating its state.